# Complex Bash loop structure in Python3 script

Tags: python, bash

I want to run a (complex) Bash while loop from a Python3 script.
I know os.subprocess and os.subprocess.check_output works in this case, but I can't wrap my head around how to include the while inside a Python subprocess.

```
while read -r line
do
    if [ "$(echo "$line" | cut -d : -f 7)" = "/bin/bash" ] && [ $(printf "$(echo "$line" | cut -d : -f 1)" | wc -c) -gt $mida ]
    then
        echo $line | cut -d : -f 1
    fi
done < /etc/passwd
```

I've tried the following:

```
out=subprocess.check_output(""" while read -r line; do; if [ "$(echo "$line" | cut -d : -f 7)" = "/bin/bash" ] && [ $(printf "$(echo "$line" | cut -d : -f 1)" | wc -c) -gt $mida ]; then; echo $line | cut -d : -f 1; fi; done < /etc/passwd """, shell=True)
```

Comment: your script doesn't work even run outside of python, it's got quoting issues

Comment: You could pack the script code into a (temporary) file and run that.

Comment: If you use triple-quotes anyway, why do you stuff it all into one long unreadable line?

Comment: The complex can be made simple though...

Comment: This seems like a job for `awk` instead of a shell loop: `awk -F: '($7=="/bin/bash" && length($1)>[insert $mida value here]) {print $1}' /etc/passwd`. Or if you want to use a shell loop, at least get `read` to do the field-splitting for you: `IFS=: read username pw uid gid longname homedir shell`.

Comment: Or `while IFS=: read -ra line; do if [[ ${line[-1]} == /bin/bash && ${#line[0]} -gt $mida ]]; then echo "${line[0]}"; fi; done < /etc/passwd`

Comment: Why use subprocess - why not do that in python instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just include it normally. Like it is. You are using `"""` quotes anyway.

```
out = subprocess.check_output("""
while read -r line
do
    if [ "$(echo "$line" | cut -d : -f 7)" = "/bin/bash" ] && [ $(printf "$(echo "$line" | cut -d : -f 1)" | wc -c) -gt $mida ]
    then
        echo $line | cut -d : -f 1
    fi
done < /etc/passwd
""", shell=True)
```

Notes:

- you should export `mida` environment variable before using it. When `$mida` variable is not set will result in some `[: something expected but not there` messages.
- `printf "$(stuff)" | wc -c`? Just `stuff | wc -c`.
- Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net
- Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001
- Just split the line on `:` using `IFS` when reading instead of using `cut`
- And that said, do not use shell - use python and write the logic in python.